# I'm experience a launch error when trying to run a job

Tags: etl, aws-glue

So I'm trying to run a job on AWS, but every time I do, the run fails and I get the following error:

I'm not sure where to look or what the problem is. I'm new and still learning, and guidance to pinpoint and rectify the issue would be highly appreciated.

Tried changing the policies for the bucket in question, but I'm not sure if I added the right policy.

This is the policy for the bucket:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "glue.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::awsglueudemycourse-ahmed98-etl-artifacts/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the policy for the job role for the job I'm Trying to run:

```json
{
  "Resources": {
    "gluejobrole1": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
      "Properties": {
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": {
                "Service": "glue.amazonaws.com"
              }
            }
          ],
          "Version": "2012-10-17"
        },
        "ManagedPolicyArns": [
          {
            "Fn::Join": [
              "",
              [
                "arn:",
                {
                  "Ref": "AWS::Partition"
                },
                ":iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSGlueServiceRole"
              ]
            ]
          }
        ],
        "RoleName": "gluejobrole1"
      }
    },
    "glueriamole1inlinepolicy": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Policy",
      "Properties": {
        "PolicyDocument": {
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Action": "s3:*Object",
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::awsglueudemycourse-ahmed98-etl-targets/*"
            },
            {
              "Action": "s3:GetObject*",
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::crawlerahmed982022101/crawlerfiles/lab1/csv/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::awsglueudemycourse-ahmed98-etl-artifacts/gluejob1/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::awsglueudemycourse-ahmed98-etl-targets/*"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "Version": "2012-10-17"
        },
        "PolicyName": "glueriamole1inlinepolicy",
        "Roles": [
          {
            "Ref": "gluejobrole1"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: LAUNCH ERROR | Error downloading from S3 for bucket: awsglueudemycourse-ahmed98-etl-artifacts, key: gluejob-artifacts/gluejob1/gluejob1script.py.Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Please refer logs for details.

Comment: sorry guys this is the error I keep getting: " LAUNCH ERROR | Error downloading from S3 for bucket: awsglueudemycourse-ahmed98-etl-artifacts, key: gluejob-artifacts/gluejob1/gluejob1script.py.Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Please refer logs for details."

Comment: Please do **not** post the error message in the comments; **edit & update** your post instead (and delete the irrelevant comments).

Answer (score 0):

The error refers to: `gluejob-artifacts/gluejob1/gluejob1script.py`

Note that it begins with: `gluejob-artifacts/gluejob1/`

However, your S3 permissions only grant access to `/gluejob1/*`. That is why it is failing.

The IAM Policy should refer to: `awsglueudemycourse-ahmed98-etl-artifacts/gluejob-artifacts/gluejob1/*`:

```
{
  "Action": "s3:GetObject*",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Resource": [
    "arn:aws:s3:::crawlerahmed982022101/crawlerfiles/lab1/csv/*",
    "arn:aws:s3:::awsglueudemycourse-ahmed98-etl-artifacts/gluejob-artifacts/gluejob1/*", # <-- This line
    "arn:aws:s3:::awsglueudemycourse-ahmed98-etl-targets/*"
  ]
}
```